Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.27 <from@example.org>: Sender address rejected: Domain exampl
I'm trying to use the mailer service to send emails through Symfony. As my website is hosted on hostinger as well as my domain I am following the following pattern in the .env file

###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=smtp://contato@mydomain.com:password_webmail@smtp.hostinger.com:465
###< symfony/mailer ###

When executing the test command "php bin/console mailer:test scheherazadesenpai@gmail.com" I am getting the following response:
In SmtpTransport.php line 333:                                                                                                                                                     Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.27 from@example.org: Sender address rejected: Domain example   e.org does not accept mail (nullMX)".
I don't know what to do because everything seems to be configured correctly

Did you read the error message? Who are you trying to send to?

I understand that at least some part of the information has been anonymised, but the root problem is that you can't send email on behalf of random addresses any more. Mail providers got strict on that. To use your hosting provider's email service, you need to send messages from a domain that's been authorised to do so. Typically, you'll have a control panel to set up domains (or it'll be a separate purchase, depending on your plan).

hosting sites normally have mail SMTP port blocked or reserved for their internal  mail services.
Be sure that port 25, 587 and/or 465 are open, depending on which are you using or your hosting provider blocked.

DNS domain example.org specified via its MX DNS record that it DOES NOT  accept incoming emails.
It makes email server you use reject envelope sender with example.com domain because example.org will not accept (eventual) bounce messages/emails.
see RFC-7505 :  A "Null MX" No Service Resource Record for Domains That Accept No Mail
